# How to add a Xunit TraitAttribute to unit tests generated by specflow

Tags: specflow, xunit, gherkin

I am using Specflow with Xunit and what I want is to have the (under the covers) generated unit tests have an `Xunit.TraitAttribute` added to them. Is that possible with Gherkin and SpecFlow?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what will guide how you would decide which ones should have the attributes? Unless it's a blanket rule, you'll want something that gives you more control than having the same attribute uniformly added to every generated test. Assuming there are T4 templates involved, you could obviously do something in there - bit the bottom line is that angle of attack is going to be messy.

You could so it as a post compile step with `Mono.Cecil` handily enough. Obviously PostSharp could do stuff like that too, but it might be overkill.